# Converting an Excel chart to an image

Tags: java, image, excel, charts

Can we convert an excel chart to image and save it as image file?

Comment: [This article](http://peltiertech.com/export-chart-as-image-file/) describes how to export an Excel chart as an image using VBA.

Comment: Just a note for anyone else that is looking to create an image. If you're using Excel 2010 you may have to activate the chart before you export it as an image, oChart.Activate.

Comment: You shouldn't have to activate the chart. The Export method goes with the chart, not the chart object (which is a common problem people have when they discover that they need to activate the chart to make something work).

Answer (score 0):

I had to work out something similar in one of my projects. It was about translating charts from an application to a dashboard running live-data.
My solution ended up by connecting to the application's database via ODBC and reverse-engineering the generation of the charts(reports) with VBA

Step by step:

```
 1. do an automatic refresh of data by setting a refresh interval in the Excel Data Query
 2. extract the information from the Excel worksheet with VBA
 3. generate Pivot Tables and Pivot Charts upon the information extracted with VBA
 4. convert the Pivot Charts or Range of Cells(=Tables) to Images and Paste them above the Chart Objects in the Excel Worksheets
 5. cut area(s) from the Worksheets (that contained the chart or tables) by giving dimensions and save these as images
 6. read the images saved at the previous stage via a webpage ( depending on its additional content either static-.html or dynamic
.aspx )
 7. set a refreshment time in the webpage source, and there is the dashboard
```

As you can notice above, I did not convert the charts to images, but rather the areas of the Worksheet that contained the Charts into images.

This is the VBA code that might help you:

```
Sub Pivot_Chart_And_Table_of_Auftragsart_To_Image()
'the code for selecting successively the areas of Pivot Table and Pivot Chart and save them as image file types .jpg to a defined directory path

 'below you set the Range(=Area in the Worksheet) you want to export to file
Dim rgExp As Range

Set rgExp = Range("A1:E5")

''' Copy range as picture onto Clipboard
rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
''' Create an empty chart with exact size of range copied
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)
.Name = "nameOfTheObjectHerewithGenerated"
.Border.LineStyle = xlNone  'this removes the border line of the temporary Chart Object
.Activate
End With

''' Paste into chart area, export to file 
ActiveChart.Paste

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("nameOfTheObjectHerewithGenerated").Chart.Export "C:\whateverDirectoryYouWish\nameOfImage.jpg"
```